# How to define a List<string> property in RDFS/OWL?

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

To define a property that is a string we can use:

```
ex:name rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
rdfs:domain ex:Person ;
rdfs:range xsd:string .
```

To define a property that is a list we can use:

```
ex:colors  rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
rdfs:domain ex:TrafficLight ;
rdfs:range rdf:List .
```

But how to define a property that is a List of string?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no list in OWL, but there are some approaches how to model lists in OWL, see [here](https://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2006/submissions/slides/7.1_Drummond.pdf) Otherwise, in RDF there are collections, read [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdf-collections), but this won't work with OWL reasoning.

Comment: Related question : [Defining a property whose range is an ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786379/defining-a-property-whose-range-is-an-ordered-list)