# Defining a property whose range is an ordered list

Tags: list, owl, protege

Given two classes `Container` and `Element`, I would like to define a property `contains` to describe the contents of a `Container`.

However, the order of `Elements` is important, so I can't simply write

```
_:container :contains _:element1, _:element2, _:element3 .
```

How can I define the `contains` property correctly?

I've looked at `rdf:List` and `owl:Seq` but I don't know how to translate that into my ontology.

Comment: Please read [this paper](https://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2006/submissions/slides/7.1_Drummond.pdf) about lists in OWL.

Comment: That's very useful. So I have to define my own `ElementList` in the ontology?

Comment: I wouldn't say "have to". It's just one way of modeling lists in OWL. But yes, you could implement it in the same way or just the part that you need. For completeness, the corresponding research paper with more details, the list of axioms and reasoning consequences is [here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~drummond/publications/OWLListsPaper/owl-lists-iswc.pdf). Hope this helps, and once you found an appropriate solution, feel free to share it here to help other people. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can define your property in many ways depending on what your requirements and your use cases are.

First, it is sometimes possible to avoid using lists or sequences completely, and yet keep the ordering of things. This can be done if the elements that you are ordering have an intrinsic order. For instance, if you want to name the children of someone from the oldest to the youngest, you can just use a `hasChild` relation:

```
ex:someone  onto:hasChild  ex:child3, ex:child1, ex:child2 .
ex:child1  onto:birthDay  "1995-10-25"^xsd:date .
ex:child2  onto:birthDay  "1997-03-10"^xsd:date .
ex:child3  onto:birthDay  "2003-01-14"^xsd:date .
```

If you do not have the exact dates, it is also possible to use a relation `isOlderThan` to make the order explicit. However, this cannot work in many cases. If you want to say in which order participants to a race arrived at the finish line, you cannot say:

```
ex:runner1  onto:arrivedBefore  ex:runner2 .
# etc.
```

because this only applies to this particular race. One solution is to use an RDF list like so:

```
ex:race42  onto:arrival  (ex:runner1 ex:runner2 ex:runner3) .
```

However, RDF lists cannot be used like this in OWL DL. The typical way of dealing with such lists in OWL is what is described in the document that AKSW links to in his comment. That is, you define a class and properties that mimic the RDF list constructs:

```
ex:container42  onto:contains  [
    a  listonto:OWLList;
    listonto:hasElement  ex:element1;
    listonto:hasNext  [
        a  listonto:OWLList;
        listonto:hasElement  ex:element2;
        listonto:hasNext  [
            a  listonto:OWLList;
            listonto:hasElement  ex:element3;
            listonto:hasNext  listonto:emptylist
        ]
    ]
] .
```

This is not the only solution. Using `rdf:Seq` is also an option (though usually discouraged by many people). Again, this cannot be used in OWL DL. However, one can introduce an ontology that partially mimics the way `rdf:Seq` works:

```
ex:container42  onto:contains  [
    a  seqonto:Sequence;
    seqonto:hasSlots
        [ a seqonto:Slot; seqonto:content ex:element1; seqonto:position 1 ],
        [ a seqonto:Slot; seqonto:content ex:element2; seqonto:position 2 ],
        [ a seqonto:Slot; seqonto:content ex:element3; seqonto:position 3 ],
    seqonto:numberOfElements 3
] .
```

The property `position` with its number are used to mimic the properties `rdf:_1`, `rdf:_2`, etc. from the RDF vocabulary. Other ways of identifying the last slot could be a special `seqonto:lastSlot` property. Note that this is what the [ordered list ontology](http://smiy.sourceforge.net/olo/spec/orderedlistontology.html) does.

There may be other options, probably as involved as the ones discussed here, but I think it covers most possibilities well enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is quite comprehensive. Could you explain why the usage of `owl:Seq` is discouraged?

Comment: It is `rdf:Seq`, not `owl:Seq`. There are several issues with it. First, it requires the use of different properties for each element in the sequence (`rdf:_1`, `rdf:_2`, etc.) which is cumbersome both for editing and processing (especially for querying). Second, nothing enforces any regularity, such as starting the sequence with `rdf:_1`, having all numbers between the first and last element, having a unique element at a given position, etc. Third, it is not possible to know that the sequence is complete because there is no indicator of the last element of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps can you find a partial answer in this paper :

P. Ciccarese ans S. Peroni, *The Collections Ontology: creating and handling collections in OWL 2 DL frameworks*, 2013 [Source](http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/system/files/swj506.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting too.